# Edited value not reflected in managed bean

Tags: jsf, richfaces, managed-bean, ajax4jsf

I am trying to edit values (say Name) populated in jsf data table. 
The snippet of jsf edit value form is as below.

```
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputLabel value="Name"></h:outputLabel>
</f:facet>
<h:inputText 
value="#{maintenancedisplay.carrierMaintenanceResult.name}" > 
</h:inputText>
</h:column>

<a4j:region>
<a4j:commandButton value="Save"
onclick="#{rich:component('ajexLoad')}.show();"
oncomplete="#{rich:component('ajexLoad')}.hide();"
title="Save Details"
action="#{maintenancedisplay.saveChanges}"
reRender="growlGrp,modelpanelGroup1" immediate="true">
</a4j:commandButton>
</a4j:region>
```

But on click of `save` button, the old value is going back to the managed bean not the edited value.

I have tried adding the `binding attribute` as below. But still it is not working.

```
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputLabel value="name"></h:outputLabel>
</f:facet>
<h:inputText 
value="#{maintenancedisplay.carrierMaintenanceResult.name}" binding="#{maintenancedisplay.name}"> 
</h:inputText>
</h:column>
```

After adding the binding attribute, changed the setter method as follows:

```
public void setname(HtmlInputText  name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("name:" + name.getValue());
    }
```

In the console log, I am getting old value not the updated value.

Please point me the mistake i'm doing here.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: `binding` is never a valid solution to this kind of problems. Get rid of it. As to your concrete problem, why exactly did you use `immediate="true"`? Are you using JSF 1.x or so?

Comment: @ BalusC its Jsf 1.2. This is the default attribute value i have used..pls corect me if i'm wrong

Comment: Why exactly did you specify `immediate` attribute? If you had no idea why, just remove it.

Comment: @ BalusC tried removing the `immediate` attribute. but the same problem exists.

Comment: Good. That can now be excluded from probable causes. Next step is `<a4j:region>`. What exactly does it do, do you think?

Comment: only the portion enclosed between `<a4j:region>` tags will be processed..not the entire view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem mentioned in the question is solved when the additional `<a4j:region>` tag around `<a4j:commandButton>` is removed from the jsf from.

The updated snippet is

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Save"
onclick="#{rich:component('ajexLoad')}.show();"
oncomplete="#{rich:component('ajexLoad')}.hide();"
title="Save Details"
action="#{maintenancedisplay.saveChanges}"
reRender="growlGrp,modelpanelGroup1" >
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Thanks BalusC for insights and suggestions.